# How to setup swagger into project with multiple API?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, swagger

I'm trying to set up Swagger for my project. My project includes 2 Asp.net core APIs. [image]

I have added Core.dll reference into Gateway. And config in startup.cs as screen.

[image]

And error "**Failed to load API definition.** ". Please help me how to fix this error!

Comment: Make sure that all of your apis have HttpVerb attribute like [HttpGet] or [HttpPost]

Comment: try Swashbuckle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio